# Require specific access for certain pages with only one input field

Tags: 7, users

For certain pages i have to require a login first (custom form with 1 input field).

- When you try to reach the URL of one of those pages you are
  redirected to a login-page
- They have to fill-in a number of 11 digits. If the filled in field
  contains 11 digits they are redirected to the protected page(s).

It's not an age gate. It's for doctors the have to fill in a 11-digit code. If the code contains 11 digital characters they can see the protected page(s).

How (which modules) are best practices to built this functionality?

Comment: The first part is easy, just add a required permission on the restricted pages. If a user is not permitted to view that page, he is automatically redirected to the login page. Can you clarify the 11-digit field? Is it some kind of captcha?

Comment: no not captcha. Just a boolean field. The only validation of this field is that it needs to have 11 digits.

Comment: that needs to be saved in cookies/db? what exactly needs to be achieved? Is it kind of a age-gate?

Comment: A boolean field can only be true or false. I think you mean a textfield which only validates if it contains 11 (random?) digits, am I right?

Comment: yes you are wright! @nikunj see my updated question

Comment: IMO this is not a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72983 ... This question here is NOT asking for 2 login form, but only to "get redirected to '***A***' (= 1 ...) login page". Therefor I think it should no longer be marked as such (which is why I used the 'reopen' link below it). To Mees: if you agree, please try to EDIT your question to make it more clear why it is not a duplicate (and let me know via an extra comment if it ever gets reopened please).

Answer (score 0):

so the characters can be random or need to be verified against some database table entries?

best thing would be to have a custom code/solution for this, use ctools popup and custom javascript to check for the right cookies on the selected pages, we can add a field defining the setting whether the page requires verification or not, and overridden node tpl (template) for that particular content type which can contain drupal_add_js or inline javascript based on the field condition. Adding a module and customising will add more pain in my opinion.