# Custom login for specific role

Tags: 7, users

On a site there are some pages from a Content-type. Some of those pages (for the Belgium language only) need to be **only** accessible for Dokters.

So when you try to reach the `URL` of one of those pages you are redirected to a login-page.

But the role 'dokters' needs to have an extra login-field. **Or only this field to login is even better if thats possible!** It should be a field with 11 digits. Or if this is to complicated (Username, Password, 11-digit field).

How (which modules) are best practices to built this functionality?

**UPDATE:**

Now i managed to do a workaround with [Content Access module](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access). I made a role 'doctor'. And now **only** users with role 'doctor' can access those pages.

But is there something to do like when the Doctors visit those restricted pages they are redirected to a custom login-page. On this page you have a small form: *Fill in your 11-digit code to access this page.*

Because all doctors have their own 11-digit code. We don't have to send all doctors the *username* name and *password* for role 'doctor', instead they can access the content directly, with their 11-digit code! The only validation should be that the field contains 11 digits.

How do i manage this in the simplest/best way?

Comment: I'm sure something like this was asked before. I'll try to find a link when I'll have a while. But -  any reason why you want to treat them differently?

Comment: @Mołot because in the best possible scenario i want the doctors to login with only an 11 digit number like i [asked here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186691/require-specific-login-page-for-certain-pages/186729#186729)

Comment: @Mołot so basically what i need i think is a conditional login-form. You have normal user login or you can login as a doctor. If you select checkbox 'login as Doctor' an extra field is added to the login form. Or am i thinking to complicated? I just have some pages on the site which require authentication with i.a. 11-digit number.

Comment: If there are certain pages which can only be viewed by docters, isn't it a better solution to create a custom permission which you grant to the doctors role? Or are those digits related to the restricted pages?

Comment: @Patrick Scheffer no the digits are not related to the restricted pages. Ok and how do i create a custom permission for those pages?

Comment: Can all doctors view all digit-protected pages? And do you want the doctor to login after entering the 11 digit code or is granting access to the content enough (in this case the user remains anonymous)?

Comment: yes all doctors (who has their 11-digit number) can see all those pages. Yes i want the doctor to login after entering the 11 digit code. Without login they can see the rest of the site like all other people.

Comment: @Patrick Scheffer is that possible some how?

Comment: Of course, anything's possible. :P However, I can't think of a module which does this so I think this would be custom code. You could create a form which logs the user in after entering the 11-digit code, but I don't know if that's very secure. An 11-digit code is fairly easy to hack by brute force..

Answer (score 0):

First, create a custom permission:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function MY_MODULE_permission() {
  return array(
    'access doctor content' => array(
      'title' => t('Access content for doctors'),
    )
  );
}
```

If the restricted content is a custom page you can do this:

```
/**
* Implements hook_menu().
*/
function MY_MODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();    
  $items['doctor_page'] = array(
    'title' => 'Doctor page',
    'page callback' => '_doctor_page_content',
    'access arguments' => array('access doctor content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

If the restricted content is a node make sure there is a reliable way to filter that content in your code (e.g. by adding a checkbox 'Protected' to the node). Set access restrictions on nodes like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_access().
 */
function MY_MODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  // Check if the content is protected.
  if (!empty($node->field_protected_content[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) {
    // If so, check if the user has access to it.
    if (user_access('access doctor content', $account)) {
      // Allow access.
      return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
    }
    // Deny access.
    return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
  }

  // Handle the default restrictions.
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

Don't forget to add your custom permission to the user role via the permissions page (`admin/people/permissions`).

Comment: Is it not easier to do above with [Nodeaccess](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) module?

Comment: Yes, the same can be achieved with that module. However, it brings a lot of extra functionality, more than you need. The grants tab shows all user roles so you need to be careful which role you select and only give it the view permission. But if you don't mind that, it is a useful module.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I **Update** my question above.